# Is there a shorter way to write this in C# 8?

Tags: c#, .net, null, null-coalescing-operator, null-conditional-operator

```
if (value2 != null)
{
    value1 = value2;
}
```

*?* and *??* operators don't seem to be useful here. I thought of using the ternary operator.

```
value1 = (value2 != null) ? value2 : value1;
```

Doesn't seem good. Is there a shorter way?

Comment: `value1 = value2 ?? value1` ?

Comment: There's `??=` that would allow setting `value1` only if it's null but no way to *prevent* assignment if the new value is null. In C# 9 and 10 NRTs are used to detect and prevent nulls but no way to prevent assignment. `value1 = value2 ?? value1` re-assigns the original value, it doesn't prevent the assignment

Comment: Why is it important to make it shorter? The `if` statement you are currently using makes your intention very clear, and it also prevents an unnecessary assignment of `value1 = value1` in the case where `value2 == null` (which is the case when using the ternary operator).

Comment: I agree with @AstridE. The original code is clear and efficient. No need to change it.

Answer (score 8):

It seems that this is the closest:

```
value1 = value2 ?? value1;
```

I feel like your original `if` is more readable.

The `??` operator is most useful if you use it within an expression. Like this:

```
var x = (value2 ?? value1) * System.Math.Pi();
```

Comment: @esege - No, when `value2` is `null` then `value1` is assigned to `value1` (i.e. no change). Just like your `if` statement.

Comment: @esege Please test it first.

Comment: @esege, Enigmativity is right, the answer is functionaly equivalent to your answer (and except when you have quite bizarre performance constraints I would say exactly exactly equivalent).

Comment: @esege why not prevent the null value before you reach the assignment? `value1 = value2 ?? value1;` works but is less clear than the `if` block - you yourself are getting confused by this right now. Where does `value2` come from? Why not prevent it from becoming null in the first place by eg checking the parameter or input it came from?

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pIDhN2

doesn't seem so @Enigmativity

Comment: @esege `value2` is `string.Empty`, not `null`. [Using your original solution](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yRS6IQ) you can see the same behaviour.

Comment: @esege - https://dotnetfiddle.net/QPh0JE it does when you use `null`.

Comment: With meaningful names (not `value1` and `value2`) the `??` version reads much more easily than the `if` version, IMO. Example: `existingValue = newValue ?? existingValue`. Succinct and meaningful.

Comment: @JohnWu - Fair enough.